# express-jwt middleware uses full paths instead of subpaths when used with express routers

Tags: node.js, api, express, jwt, express-jwt

I am using Node/Express.js to build an API. The API is present in the `/api` prefix if the prefix is not set, then Express server will return a Vue JS frontend. So basically I want `express-jwt` to get used as a middleware only when the `/api` prefix is set. For that reason I am using express `router` by doing `app.use('/api, router)`.

And in the router file, I am using the `express.jwt` with unless syntax, to prevent any unauthorized access.

I also made the choice to implement `express-jwt` in the router file because I don't want to add `/api/somepath` in the `express-jwt.unless`, instead, I would like it to use `/somepath` and consider it as `/api/somepath` because I am using it with the router.

My router file:

```
const router = require('express').Router()
    const routeController = require('./routeController')
    const ejwt = require('express-jwt')
    const config = require('../config/config')

    // Protected Routes
    // Protect Routes
    router.use(
      ejwt({
        secret: config.APP_SECRET,
        getToken: req => {
          const { token } = req.body
          if (token) return token
          return null
        }
      }).unless({
        path: ['/', '/auth/generateToken']
      })
    )

    router.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
        res.status(401).send({
          status: false,
          message: 'Access Forbidden'
        })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    })
```

This didn't work for me. Whenever I try to access the frontend with `/`, the `express-jwt` middleware gets triggered and I can't even access my frontend. I can get this working If I also provide it all of my frontend routes as well. Which is not an all a good idea because the frontend has a lot of paths.

In short, I want the middleware to only check for the token if the path has `/api` prefix set. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: What is the status code of the response when you try to access `/`???

Comment: {
    "status": false,
    "message": "Access Forbidden"
}

Comment: I figured it out! needed to do `router.use('/api', ejwt())`